# onclick function is not working using handlebars js

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

I'm using **handlebars js** row template with **react js** but somehow the onClick function is not working from that row template.
Following is the code snippet:

```
// React Class
class Demo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showList = this
            .showList
            .bind(this);
    };

    // Showlist function
    showDocumentList() {
        console.log("Show Doc list function called");
    };

    createHandleTemplate(e) {
        return Handlebars.compile("<div><button primary={true} data-automation-id = 'test' class = \" document - bu" +
            "tton primary - btn - height document - btn - \" title = 'Show list' onClick = \"" +
            " () => this.showList()\" > <span class=\"document-button-label\">Show List</span" +
            "> < /button></div > ");
    };

    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "container" >
            <
            div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
                {
                    __html: this.createHandleTemplate(this)
                }
            } > < /div> < /
            div >
        );
    }
};
```

Please guide me to fix this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show us more code? as where the `onClick` event resides and so, maybe the render method also

Comment: Hi @EliasGhali, I have updated the post with sample code.